# Prevent redirects in AngleSharp

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Is it possible to prevent any redirects when doing requests like

```
var context = BrowsingContext.New(new Configuration().WithDefaultLoader().WithCookies());
var response = await context
                        .Configuration
                        .Services
                        .OfType<HttpRequester>()
                        .First()
                        .RequestAsync(
                            new Request
                            {
                                Address = AngleSharp.Url.Create(url),
                                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                            },
                            CancellationToken.None);
```

or catch them?

Comment: The redirects are handled from the loader - hence going replacing the `WithDefaultLoader()` with your own loader could help here. By default there is no thing to interrupt redirects (on HTTP level).

Comment: should be useful here - https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/issues/696#issuecomment-408513260